# trigger.io Scroll to Top with Native topbar

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to make the trigger.io native topbar scroll the webview to the top on click? I can't see an obvious way to listen for clicks on the topbar other than on buttons. We have a long list and would like to make clicking on the bar scroll the page to the top much like Safari does when you click the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way of detecting clicks on the topbar from javascript. You could however add a button to the topbar and use `$(window).scrollTop()` in the button clicked event.

Comment: What's the best way to log a feature request for that?

Comment: Best to send an email to support@trigger.io